# Ionic/AngularJs Controller Initialization ng-init doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Onced logged my controller initialization script doesn't invoke:

Go to https://billiving-qa.azurewebsites.net/accountant 
email: qa@billiving.com 
pass: 111111

When going to manage accounts the drop down list is empty. If you refresh (hit f5) the list gets populated. Then if you go into incognito or delete cache and reload the page the list is empty again.

It seems that the initialization is invoked late in the lifetime of my single-page-application.

Here's my code:

```
<ion-view hide-back-button="true" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl" ng-init="Initialize()">


  <ion-nav-title align-title="center">



  <select ng-options="account.Key as account.Name for account in accounts" ng-change="LoadAccount(account)" 
  ng-model="account.Key">
<option value='' disabled selected>Select Account..</option>
</select>

<a style="cursor: pointer" ng-click="Initialize()">Refresh</a>


  </ion-nav-title>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">

  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="page page-dashboard is-pad" style="height:100%">


<iframe frameborder="5" class="frm" ng-src="{{trustSrc(url)}}" scrolling="yes"></iframe>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's the angularjs code:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')

    .controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $http, AppConfig, Utils, AuthService, $state, $sce) {
          Utils.hideIndicator();
          if (!AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
            $state.go('app.login');
            return;
    }

    $scope.accounts = {};
    $scope.account ={};
    $scope.url = 'about:blank';

    if (localStorage.SelectedKey!=null){
      $scope.account.Key = localStorage.SelectedKey;
      SetAccount($scope.account);
    }


    $scope.Initialize = function(){



      Utils.showIndicator();
      $http.get(AppConfig.endpoint + 'accountants/accounts')
                        .then(function (response) {
                          $scope.accounts = response.data;

                          if ($scope.accounts.length==0)
                            $state.go('app.register');

                          Utils.hideIndicator();
                        });
    };


    $scope.LoadAccount = function(account){
          SetAccount(account);
    };

    function SetAccount(account) {
          $scope.url = AppConfig.BaseAccount + "/Users/Index.aspx?userkey=" + account.Key;
          localStorage.SelectedKey = account.Key;
    }

    $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 issues:

1. You define the DashboardCtrl twice! Once in the route config and once in the dashboard.html template.
2. Why do you use ng-init? Just load the accounts while the initialization of the controller. Remove the `ng-init` and call Initialize directly.

EDIT:

The DashboardCtrl get initialized at startup, as it is the default page. You do a redirect to the login page, but the DashboardCtrl and it's page will be cached by **ionic framework**. After login the DashboardCtrl won't be initialized again.

maybe you can do a hard reload

```
$state.go('app.dashboard', {}, {reload: true});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've removed the extra DashboardCtrl and the init function and still having the same issue. I've upload to server so you can refresh and see. Thanks!

Comment: The reload didn't work, I reverted to loading the whole page. Anyways, you threw me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue when using Ionic, that is the ng-init wouldn't worked after the second time onward. This is because of the caching mechanism within the framework. It is somehow useful also. But in some case we may not need this feature. When we should reload the entire html page in order to make ng-init work, we should disable the cache for that single page by using `cache-view="false"` within the ion-view.

Reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-beta14-how-to-clean-the-cache-for-a-specific-view/14277

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't ideal for SPA, I ended up using this:

```
$state.go('app.dashboard');
$window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Apparently, you can disable cache this way:
<ion-view cache-view="false" hide-back-button="true">

That way you don't need to refresh..